# How to store data in form of object into firestore using swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store data into object form using swift language.The data structure of the data base is like

```
collection/
document/
collection/
document1/:
           Invitess1(object) :
                              name :"santosh"
                              phone :1234567890 
          Invitee2(object) :
                              name :"sam"
                              phone:1234654768
          .....
document 2/
          Initee1(object) :

                           name:"red"
                           phone:4654343532
         .......
```

is it possible to store data like this? if possible how to do it? i tried like this :

```
for var i in 0..<n { // n is no.of selected contacts
            for var j  in i...i {
                print("amount is \(d[i])")
                print("phone number is \(num[j])")
                let dataToSave:[String: Any] = ["name" :"vijayasri",
                                                "PhoneNumber":num[j],
                                                "Amount": d[i],
                                                ]
            }

        }
        var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = self.db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document("nothing").collection("Split").addDocument(data: dataToSave){
            error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error adding document:\(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                print("Document ades with ID:\(ref!.documentID)" )
            }

        }


    }
```

But it doesn't work. How to do it..

Comment: Your data to save is not correctly formatted. According to your diagram, your documents will need to store an array of objects, but your example is not an array. Your example is a single object. [Read this regarding array storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)

Comment: is it possible to store data like that in ios? The document which is you share in that it is only for one single object in document. But i want multiple object form to be stored into single document. and the field values are also applied in dynamic way not static way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your example code is never going to work as intended since `dataToSave` is overwritten every iteration of the `j` loop. Your inner `j` loop probably has a typo at `i...i`*

To store multiple objects in one document, create the document in Swift with multiple objects in it. Since you know how to encode your object as `[String:Any]`, just take those dictionaries combine into a larger `[String:Any]`document.

I would change your code to be more like:

```
var dataToSave: [String:Any] = []()
for var i in 0..<n { // n is no.of selected contacts
    var inProcess: [String:Any] = []()
    for var j  in i...i {
        print("amount is \(d[i])")
        print("phone number is \(num[j])")
        let detail: [String: Any] = ["name" :"vijayasri",
                                     "PhoneNumber":num[j],
                                     "Amount": d[i]]
        inProcess["NextKey\(j)"] = detail
     }
    dataToSave["SomeKey\(i)"] = inProcess
 }

 var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
 ref = self.db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document("nothing").collection("Split").addDocument(data: dataToSave){
        error in
        if let error = error {
            print("error adding document:\(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {
            print("Document ades with ID:\(ref!.documentID)" )
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Ok it works. It stored like what i need. I change the inprocess(j) to inprocess(i).